# Count dates of the last 3 years - show them as completed and not completed

Tags: php, select, mysqli, group-by, partition

Count all dates of the last 3 years - completed (if all reports have been submitted) and not completed (if one report is missing) and output it as a list.

There is a table with the appointments. 
Each appointment has a date and an ID. 
For each appointment, there are events (table 2 with the ID of the appointment), which are concluded with a report. Only if all events have a report (in table 2 "Report available?" = 1), then the appointment is closed, otherwise, it is still open.

I want to point out the last three years for example:

2019 x closed appointments from appointments...
2018...
2017...

I thought I'd count the related events and take the sum of the submitted reports. This also works for the individual dates, but if I bundle them in the years, the sums are calculated incorrectly.

```
  $sql = "SELECT termine.*,YEAR(termine.datummysql) as jahr,COUNT(termin_shopbesuche.berichtstatus) As shopsmitbericht,SUM(termin_shopbesuche.berichtstatus) As summeshops 
FROM termine 
LEFT JOIN termin_shopbesuche ON termine.__id_termin = termin_shopbesuche._id_termin 
WHERE termine._id_asm = ? AND YEAR(termine.datummysql) >= ? 
GROUP BY YEAR(termine.datummysql) Order By datummysql";
```

Comment: can you try it without group by?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it now: I needed a subquery in which I got a 1 or 0 with Case. From this result I group the years.